# Ionic3 The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngx-translate

hi it's been days since I've tried to solve this problem without success.
When I try to use the pipe translate i get this error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("
<ion-content padding>
<h2>{{[ERROR ->]"HELLO" | translate }}</h2>
</ion-content>
"): ng:///AdminPannelPageModule/AdminPannelPage.html@11:8
```

I am using angular 5.

these are the versions I use for translation

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
```

Npm install

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

This is my Home.html page

```
<h2>{{"HELLO" | translate }}</h2>
```

JSON file for translate:

```
assets/i18n/en.json

{
"HELLO": "hello"
}

assets/i18n/it.json

{
"HELLO": "ciao"
}
```

in the export I used the `export function setTranslateLoader (http: HttpClient)` instead of using the `export function setTranslateLoader (http: Http)` because if not it gave me this error: `Argument of type 'Http' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpClient '. Property 'handler' is missing in type 'Http'.`

There are my import in app.module.ts

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function setTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}


@NgModule({
imports: [
HttpClientModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (setTranslateLoader),
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
}),
],
```

And This is my app.component.ts constructor

```
constructor(..., translate: TranslateService) {
     translate.setDefaultLang('en');
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can see that you are having a sub module `AdminPannelPageModule`, where the error is actually thrown. You need to mark `TranslateModule` in that module as well, but skip `forRoot()`. So in your `AdminPannelModule`:

```
imports: [
  ....
  TranslateModule
],
```

Comment: Great! Glad to hear, have a nice day and happy coding! :) :)

Comment: @Kapilsoni, sorry, when not seeing the code, it's hard to help. You can consider posting a new question where you show what you have attempted, if this solution doesn't work, there might be something else going on. So if you ask a new question, make sure it's a [mcve] for best chances of getting help :)